# draw graph using jQuery Visualize plug

Tags: jquery, plugins, graph

I use the jQuery Visualize plug to draw graph ,it is easy to scratch data from table of a HTML page.

now,whenever you have a table in a HTML page ,this plug draws graph under the table.
now ,i have two tables in my html page,and i want the two graphs looks side by side.so i firstly put the table side by side using this:

it works,and ofcourse these two tables look side by side
BUT,
the plug doesn't work well, esecially in IE and firefox,the graphs are not shown under the tables!

if only one table ,i works well.

what is wrong? any papi could help me?
3kx

Comment: Looks like you meant to paste some code but missed.  If you could show an example on jsfiddle, it would be very helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/